# Search recursivly for a property name {String} in JSON object and return the associated value

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I am trying to search for a property name in a json and return it's value if the property can be found, or null otherwise.

```js
function returnValueAtProperty(string, exampleObject) {
  for (ch1 in exampleObject) {
    if (ch1 === string) {
      return exampleObject[ch1];
    } else if (typeof(exampleObject[ch1]) == 'object') {
      var ob = exampleObject[ch1]
      for (ch2 in ob) {
        return returnValueAtProperty(string, ob[ch2])
      }
    } else if (Array.isArray(exampleObject[ch1])) {
      var arr = exampleObject[ch1];
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
        return returnValueAtProperty(string, arr[i])
      }
    }
  }
}

var exampleObject = {
  "key0": 42,
  "key1": {
    "key2": [{
        "key3": "tag",
        "key4": false
      },
      {
        "key5": null,
        "key6": [3, 141]
      }
    ],
    "key7": null
  }
}

console.log(returnValueAtProperty("key3", exampleObject));
```

The function should return the "tag" string. or if i call the function like returnValueAtProperty("key6", exampleObject) it should return the array

Comment: do you really take `null` as flag for not found values, even if you have `null` as value inside of the object?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I am a QA and this problem was given as an exercise in a test for automation testing post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could take a single loop and return any value, as long as it is not `null`.

```js
function getValue(object, key) {
    var k, temp;
    if (key in object) return object[key];                // if found return value
    for (k in object) {                                   // iterate keys
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') { // check not null and object
            temp = getValue(object[k], key);              // get sub value, if exists
            if (temp !== null) return temp;               // if not null return value
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var object = { key0: 42, key1: { key2: [{ key3: "tag", key4: false }, { key5: null, key6: [3, 141] }], key7: null } };

console.log(getValue(object, "key3"));
console.log(getValue(object, "key6"));
console.log(getValue(object, "key7"));
console.log(getValue(object, "foo"));
```

A slightly better approach by taking `undefined` as not existend value.

```js
function getValue(object, key) {
    var k, temp;
    if (key in object) return object[key];
    for (k in object) {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            temp = getValue(object[k], key);
            if (temp !== undefined) return temp;
        }
    }
}

var object = { key0: 42, key1: { key2: [{ key3: "tag", key4: false }, { key5: null, key6: [3, 141] }], key7: null } };

console.log(getValue(object, "key3"));
console.log(getValue(object, "key6"));
console.log(getValue(object, "key7"));
console.log(getValue(object, "foo"));
```

Comment: @jujiyangasli, what is the problem where you have an answer for it?

Answer (score 0):

I just change a bit your code I believe if you change the array verification before the  object verification it will be better, in javascript even an array type  can return an object so probable the arrays its getting inside 
in the first else if  bellow I show you the code change I made

```
for(ch1 in exampleObject){
               if(typeof ch1 === string){
                   return exampleObject[ch1];
               }  else if(Array.isArray(exampleObject[ch1])){
                   var arr = exampleObject[ch1];
                   for(var i=0; i<arr.length;){
                       return returnValueAtProperty(string,arr[i])
                   }
               }
                else if(typeof(exampleObject[ch1])=='object'){
                   var ob = exampleObject[ch1]
                   for(ch2 in ob){
                        return returnValueAtProperty(string, ob[ch2])
                   }
               } 
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
function returnValueAtProperty(string,obj){

  for(var i in obj){

    if(i === string)
      return obj[i]

    else if(obj[i].constructor === Object) {
      const val = returnValueAtProperty(string, obj[i]);
      if(val) return val;
    }

  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made couple of trivial errors there.

Check this:

```js
function returnValueAtProperty(string, exampleObject) {
  for (ch1 in exampleObject) {
    if (ch1 === string) {
      return exampleObject[ch1];
    } else if (typeof(exampleObject[ch1]) == 'object') {
      var ob = exampleObject[ch1];
      return returnValueAtProperty(string, ob);
    } else if (Array.isArray(exampleObject[ch1])) {
      var arr = exampleObject[ch1];
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;++i) {
        return returnValueAtProperty(string, arr[i])
      }
    }
  }
}

var exampleObject = {
  "key0": 42,
  "key1": {
    "key2": [{
        "key3": "tag",
        "key4": false
      },
      {
        "key5": null,
        "key6": [3, 141]
      }
    ],
    "key7": null
  }
}

console.log(returnValueAtProperty("key3", exampleObject));
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! It works for that key, but if i change it with 'key5' for example it does not work!